# Per store indexing in Solr

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

We have a requirement where we have say 500 stores and skus in each store is having different prices and they change everyday. the inventory status for each also changes everyday. We want to index data from all these stores in Solr and elastic search both. What is most effective way in which we can achieve this. Also I need help for querying too when i want to display this on website.

Answer (score 2):

your question is a bit unclear, but if you are looking on how to index diff price/inventory per store, there is a very recent [Lucene Solr Revolution presentation by Erik Hatcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUi9VHS8KIc) showing how to this using Payloads (Solr recently got support for using payload stuff by Erik himself). He is actually using the same example in his presentation.